# How to display Grid data with 'filtered' binding list

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, lambda

I have to display data in a grid binded with binding list

```
BindingList<ExecutionSummaryData> ExecutionList
grid.DataSource = ExecutionList;
```

where `ExecutionSummaryData` contains property like `Name, Age, Address` etc(for example).

Now through a winform when user select certain name, age or other parameters i have to select data from `ExecutionList` and have to bind the filtered data to my grid.

1. Can I somehow bind this query to `ExecutionList` so that each time query string changed `ExecutionList` will get binded to grid and display filtered data?
2. Can I bind any sublist, retrieved from `ExecutionList` through filter string, to my grid and for each filter query change it will fetch data from `ExecutionList` and display accordingly.
3. I don't want to clear and refill data to `ExecutionList` on each filter as this grid will be getting updated real time with around 10-20 million records.

### Editing my requirement

Please suggest how what will be the syntax of Linq query or Lambda expression over this `ExecutionList` to fetch filtered record .
Filter query will be including condition with multiple entities to compare and fetch from list
like "

> Select * from `ExecutionList` where name in('N1','N2','N3',,,,'N90')"
>   AND AGE in ('A1','A2','A3',,,,'A90')

Please suggest as how can i achieve this? Based on replies I will be updating my question with missing/required info needed.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: _10-20 million records_ Really?? Sounds crazy. I think you should rethink the deisgn and filter at the dbms level istead of pumping these kind of numbers to the client. What did you try with using the Filter property? You can change it in a TextChanged event of the TextBox..

Comment: @TaW Noted for control calling. There is no RDBMS involved in it as I am retrieving data from redis(in-memory database) and subscribing to its channel where i will be getting updates & new records in milisecs.

Comment: @AshishJaiswal - so why not retrieving data from redis with provided filters?

Comment: Why you need keep 10-20 millions records and filter them, if user can see only 50 at once?

Comment: @Fabio: Not possible to filter and retrieve data every time user query for filter. This is a Financial Trading Monitoring Application thus volume of records will be huge with high frequency updates and we can't fiddle with redis latency which is tackling critical logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to filter your data from a DataTable i would suggest using a DataView

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv = new DataView(parameterDs.Tables[0], "ParameterName = '@" + parameter.Key + "'",string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

you can also use sort on DataView

```
dv.Sort = "Name";
```

and then just use

```
grid.DataSource = dv;
```

Another way to use DataView is by assigning a query to it as below:

```
DataTable contacts = dataSet.Tables["Contact"];

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from contact in contacts.AsEnumerable()
                                         where contact.Field<string>("LastName").StartsWith("S")
                                         orderby contact.Field<string>("LastName"), contact.Field<string>("FirstName")
                                         select contact;

DataView view = query.AsDataView();

bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
```

or by using the DataView 'RowFilter' Property:

```
DataTable contacts = dataSet.Tables["Contact"];

DataView view = contacts.AsDataView();

view.RowFilter = "LastName='Zhu'";

bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
```

and whenever you want to clear your filter just write:

```
view.RowFilter = null; //or String.Empty
```

you might want to take a look at the examples [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dataview) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/filtering-with-dataview-linq-to-dataset):

Comment: I am using BindingList not the DataTable or DataView

Comment: the binding list has an enumerator either, this should work the same

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure with paging and pass your search filter and retrieve date in few thousand. Or you can **IQueryable** so this will fire query based on your filter and will retrieve the data. **"This is a comment, not an answer.**"

Answer (score -1):

try
{
string EmpNo = txtEmployeeNumber.Text;
List result = ViewState["EmpList"] as List;

```
    var singleEmp = result.Where(x => x.EmployeeNo == EmpNo).FirstOrDefault();



    if (singleEmp != null)
    {

        List<EmployeeClearanceDetailsEntity> singleEmpList = new List<EmployeeClearanceDetailsEntity> { singleEmp };



        gvViewEmpList.DataSource = singleEmpList;
        gvViewEmpList.DataBind();
        gvViewEmpList.Visible = true; 
    }
```